# Search console shows my site info but google analytics don't. what should i do?

Tags: google-analytics

I've indexed my website like around 3 months ago or so; Search console shows my data about my site but google analytics is not showing any stats at all. everywhere in google analytics shows "no data available". I have to mention that when I visit google analytics, I see my property name so I think my site is linked properly.. but I can't understand why it's not showing any stats!

what should I do?

Comment: Can you provide more information on how you've implemented the google analytics code on your site? Or even provide a link to your site?

Comment: Sure. I toke the tracking code and pasted it in the header of all of my pages (through a wordpress plugin called insert headers and footers). Here's my website address=> https://www.yoouta.com

Comment: It should be tracking. Can you post a screenshot from GA?

Comment: How to send? I don’t see any icon for sharing pics here..

Comment: Upload to imgur or something and post a link. I think you’re too new to post pics.

Comment: oh, obviousely i should get more credit in order to be able to send pics.. ^_^

Comment: I'll upload it in my own site as an article. I'll remove it when we fix the problem ;). 1 minute please

Comment: https://www.yoouta.com/internet-merketing/google-analytics-screenshot/

Comment: can you click on the menu and go to "real-time"?

Comment: it's the same, zero data.

Comment: Can you confirm the property UA id?

Comment: how to confirm?

Comment: if you mean verifying, it doesn't even show me in real-time reports.

Comment: Admin>tracking info> tracking code > “Tracking ID”

Comment: nothing. I even clicked on "send test traffic". should i remove everything and create a property again? is it good decision?

Comment: It has to show something. Can you confirm by these instructions. It isn't in the mobile app. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en. I want to confirm the UA-########-1 id with you.

Comment: i see my id but i don't know how to confirm it..

Comment: the tracking code is already in all the headers of my pages..

Comment: ok, problem solved! now it's showing information!

Comment: Thank you very very much for your time and kindness. really appreciate it <3